# z-index is not being set to some value

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am setting z-index to some value for a div, but it still shows me z-index as auto in computed styles in browser.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening?
and how can I fix this?

Thanks,
Amit Chaudhary

Comment: Please put your code for better understanding

Comment: make sure you are setting the z-index in correct file... or else provide us with some code or link so that we can have a look...

Comment: corresponding code required here. **js and css**.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are also setting a position other than `static`:

```
#myDiv {
    position : relative;
    z-index  : 25;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about it that your corresponding div's z-index is controlled by some `js` code or `css`. I think you have to use the `.load()` method of the jquery to `override that elem's z-index` :

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('elem').css('z-index','99999'); // @elem put your div's id or class
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set it to be `relative` or `absolute` even if you think it is unnecessary. In the following example, if you want `a` to be upper than `b`, you should set `a` to be `absolute` even the position of `a` works if no `absolute` is set.

```
<div id="a">
    a
</div>
<div id="b">
    b
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#a {
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #f00;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}

#b {
    background-color: #0f0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Run the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/a9dMn/

Answer (score 0):

Check your cache. The styles may not apply if your browser is looking at a cached css file, in this case, the div still has no set z-index.

If you are using chrome, you can reset the cache by ctrl+f5.

Answer (score 0):

If it is being overrideen you could always try

```
.element {z-index:100 !important;}
```